# Passing values to mysql query to check a condition

Tags: mysql

I have a Mysql QUERY

```
'SELECT * 
FROM city
WHERE name = ?
ORDER BY STREETNO' [Keyname]
```

**SCENARIO**:: IF i pass a name say `sam` as `Keyname` to this query the query is functional when `where clause` & `orderby` both functional.

[NOTE]::Passing the value is dynamic by client

- But when i(Client) dont pass anything as `Keyname` to this query.... Can i still
  make sure `order by` is functional
- Is there any condition to make this happen

**Or is it not possible in Database part and must be taken care in client itself ?**

Hope i am clear

Comment: Do you run this query via PHP?

Comment: I HAVE USED EXPRESSJS

Comment: You order the query results with column name not the parameter you are passing to the query.